# Can I return a dataclass from the forward method of a pytorch Module?

Tags: python, pytorch

Can I return a dataclass from the forward method of a pytorch Module?

It appears to be possible in simple examples, and I can't find any documented obstruction. However, I've not seen it done, and coming from Tensorflow I worry that it will blow up when things get complicated (e.g. in distributed training).